# WEBSERVICE invocation in LibreOffice Calc which requires http headers

Tags: web-services, http-headers, libreoffice-calc

The [WEBSERVICE](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/WEBSERVICE) function in Libreoffice Calc allows invoking external http URLs. However, some APIs require using the request along some specific http headers. Is it possible to indicate http headers in the WEBSERVICE calls?